# How does 高出一大截 break apart in 交货时间延长好几倍，单价翻几番，残次品率高出一大截?

Tags: grammar

I'm reading an April article which predicts Trump wins the 2020 US election based on trends in manufacturing of Trump-branded merchandise in the Chinese city of [Yiwu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiwu) (known for its commodities):

> 先说一句，特朗普会把他帽子的生产线搬回美国么？当然不会。交货时间延长好几倍，单价翻几番，**残次品率高出一大截**，做一辈子生意了，这点子帐还不会算……义乌生产商也是两耳不闻窗外事，从网络到白宫草坪的骂战，都不耽误赚钱，机器轰鸣，日夜加班只为特朗普……
> <sub>[义乌再次判定：特朗普连任](https://m.k.sohu.com/d/447211719)，2020年04月30日</sub>

I'm struggling with the sentence in bold (and, in fact, the whole article is quite challenging).

> [My translation:] First, [let me] say a sentence.  Will Trump take his cap's production line and move it to the USA?  Of course not.  Delivery time will increase a few times over, unit price will increase multiple times, [and] **the defective product rate will increase by a big margin**.  After a lifetime of business, this thin (?) veil will not work…… Yiwu production merchants also pay no attention to external affairs, from the Internet to the White House lawn's war of words, it won't delay profit, machine noises, day-and-night overtime only for Trump……

While I can infer its meaning, I don't understand how 残次品率高出一大截 breaks apart.  [残次品](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%AE%8B%E6%AC%A1%E5%93%81)+[率](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%8E%87) = "defective goods rate", but the rest is not clear to me.  E.g. 高出 = "increase"?  It looks like [一大截](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E5%A4%A7%E6%88%AA) should be considered a word in itself, meaning "significant difference" (although it's [not in CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%80%E5%A4%A7%E6%88%AA)).

**Question**: How does 高出一大截 break apart in 交货时间延长好几倍，单价翻几番，残次品率高出一大截?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the context, the sentence should be interpreted as

- 残次品率 = Defective rate
- 高出 = higher than
- 一大截 = by a great distance (by a great degree)

**残次品率高出一大截** = **The defective rate** (*in American made goods*) (*will be*) **higher than** (*the defective rate in China-made goods*) **by a great degree**

截 refer to measurement of 'length' --> 'distance' --> 'degree'

The comparison between American made goods and China-made goods also apply to 交货时间延长好几倍，单价翻几番

(美国制造的商品与中国制造的商品相比:)交货时间延长好几倍，单价翻几番  = (American made goods compare to China-made goods:) The delivery time will be extended several times and the unit price will be doubled a few times

Comment: Actually 残次品 are two different categories in production:  残品 broken products;  次品 below agreed quality standard.  Both should be specified the acceptable rate in the purchase contract.  Obviously, 残次品率高出一大截 the rate is much higher than agreed/acceptable rate.  I may add that the whole quoted passage happened daily in Yiwu.  You want the cheapest?  Be prepared for 怕便宜无好货。

Comment: Sorry,got the irony the other way round.  They refer to American production.  But It's not fair except the unit prices will be much higher than that of Chinese made.

Answer (score 0):

Hiho hiho, it's off to work we go ...

先说一句，
First, let me ask,
特朗普会把他帽子的生产线搬回美国么？
will Trump move his baseball cap production back to The States? (Was it ever there??)
当然不会。
Of course not!
交货时间延长好几倍，
The delivery time would increase several-fold,
单价翻几番，
the unit price would rise several times,
残次品率高出一大截，
the defective goods rate would go up significantly,
做一辈子生意了，
I've been in business all my life,
这点子帐还不会算……（算帐）
(do you think I) don't know how to count  ....
义乌生产商也是两耳不闻窗外事，
the Yiwu production business does not bother itself with outside matters,
从网络到白宫草坪的骂战，
from the Internet to the White House lawn quarrels,
都不耽误赚钱，
none of these will interfere with our doing business,
机器轰鸣，
the rumbling of our production lines,
日夜加班只为特朗普……
day and night, working overtime, all for Trump ....